# UPDATE SELECT WITH JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

My dilemma is that I need update subscription_id's in my transaction table to new subscription_id's based on the same billerid.

My subscription table has members with multiple subscription records from different billers. I am having a hard time putting this update select/join together on mysql.

TBL subscription_id

```
+--------------------+---------------+----------+
| subscription_id    | memberid      | billerid |
+--------------------+---------------+----------+
12345                | A             | ?        |
+--------------------+---------------+----------+
67890                | A             | 13       |
+--------------------+---------------+----------+
11222                | B             | 13       |
+--------------------+---------------+----------+
91422                | B             | ?        |
+--------------------+---------------+----------+
```

TBL transaction

```
+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| trans_id      | subscription_id | billerid |
+---------------+-----------------+----------+
00012           | 12345           | 13       |
+---------------+-----------------+----------+
02013           | 12345           | 13       |
+---------------+-----------------+----------+
08013           | 11222           | 13       |
+---------------+-----------------+----------+
50013           | 11222           | 13       |
+---------------+-----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Because I did not state this properly, How would I update the trans_id 's 00012 and 02013 to have the subscription_id of 67890?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE transaction AS t
JOIN (SELECT s1.subscription_id AS old_subid, 
             s2.subscription_id AS new_subid,
             s2.billerid AS billerid
      FROM subscription_id AS s1
      JOIN subscription_id AS s2 ON s1.memberid = s2.memberid
      WHERE s1.billerid = '?'
        AND s2.billerID != '?') AS s
ON t.billerid = s.billerid AND t.subscription_id = s.old_subid
SET t.subscription_id = s.new_subid
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b11df/1)

I think I came up with a simpler version that fits your latest comment:

```
UPDATE transaction AS t
JOIN subscription_id AS s1 
    ON s1.subscription_id = t.subscription_id 
        AND s1.billerid != t.billerid
JOIN subscription_id AS s2 
    ON s1.memberid = s2.memberid 
        AND s2.subscription_id != s1.subscription_id 
        AND s2.billerid = t.billerid
SET t.subscription_id = s2.subscription_id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0efc70/1)

Comment: How would joining on just the billerid work here?  subscription_id's in the transaction table are related to records in the subscription table pertaining to different members...

Comment: Your question says it's based on the same billerid, so that's what I joined on. There's no memberid in the transaction table, so I don't see how I could use that in the join.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Perhaps you should use both `subscription_id` and `billarid`.

Comment: But `subscription_id` is what I'm updating, so it makes no sense to join on it.

Comment: @Barmar, I guess i should say how would update subscription_id for trans_id's 0012 and 02013 to be 67890 ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question (it's confusing that you have a table with the same name as the columns, I thought you wanted to update the `subscription_id` table). Why should they be updated to `67890`  and not `11222`, since both `billerid`s match? How should it know to use `memberid = A`?

Comment: @Barmar, member A and B are just examples. I need to update thousands of records in the transaction table with the same scenario. Members can have multiple records in the subscription table.  Each subscription can have multiple transactions in the transactions table. I need to update all the subscription_id's in the transaction table to the new subscription_id in the subscription table for that same member.

Comment: You still haven't explained how I'm supposed to match everything properly. Does it have something to do with the `billerid = ?` rows? Is that the old subscription ID, and I have to update the subscription ID to the one for the same member ID?

Comment: Look at my latest update, I'm still guessing the criteria you want.

Comment: @Barmar, the only way i can think to do this is to first know which transaction.subscription_id's need to be updated.  Any transaction.subscription_id with a billerid of 13 needs to be updated to a new subscription.subscription_id.  The subscription.subscription_id has to be from the same member BUT has to be the record with the billerid of 13.  So the first match has to be subscription_id's then to get the new record via the memberid match, and use the subscription.subscription_id with billerid of 13.

Comment: But why shoudn't it update trans_id 08013 and 50013? They also have billerid = 13. You have to describe clearly how it knows which ones should be updated and which ones should not.

Comment: Records for trans_id 08013 and 50013 are already correct. They are linked by subscription_id that has billerid 13 in both tables.  I need to fix (update) the records that are not correct yet.

Comment: But how can the UPDATE query tell that they're already correct? There needs to be something in the database that distinguishes correct from incorrect subscription IDs.

Comment: Yes, transaction table has records of subscription_id's that have billerid value of 13. If that same subscription_id in subscription table billerid !=13 then it needs to be updated to the correct subscription_id that has the billerid=13 based on same memberid.  I think your query is very close.